# Running Nunit Test Cases cross platform

Tags: .net-core, nunit

I have developed some End to End tests using Selenium, and Nunit.

I need to run the test cases cross-platform so I created a .net core class library project and developed the tests.

Now I am struggling with figuring how to run the tests outside visual studio.

The first step I did is publishing the project using:

```
dotnet publish project
```

Then I found out that I can run Nunit tests using nunit-console.exe, but I'm not sure that it supports cross-platform.

Is what I am trying to accomplish doable? or shall I replace Nunit with other option?

Comment: nunit-console doesn't run .NET Core tests yet - you currently need to use dotnet test to run your nunit tests. See https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to achieve running Nunit Test Cases cross platform:

1- Running `dotnet publish` project with specifying target runtime.

3- Running [`dotnet vstest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-vstest?tabs=netcore21) with specifying file containing tests.

Answer (score 1):

To run .Net Core tests, including NUnit tests, use [the `dotnet test` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test). It is cross-platform.

Comment: Thank you, I see that it requires .csproj file, so I need to copy the code to each framework then run dotnet test there?